# Как конвертировать картинку в rgba массив пикселей?

Tags: c++

Есть картинка в любом формате, нужно как-то ее конвертировать в такой массив:

```
static const uchar img[] = {
    255,255,255,100,
    0,0,0,100,
    255,0,0,100,
    0,255,0,100
};
DrawRGBA(img, weight, height);
```

Есть ли что-то для этого?

Comment: `в любом формате` — в каком именно формате? Или интересует решение для всех возможных форматов?

Comment: png, bmp, jpg и подобные, мне нужно для любого 1

Comment: imagemagick/graphicmagic/Qt/ffmpeg, если кроссплатформенно. Но получится ли "совсем все форматы" - не уверен, а 99.9% потребностей точно покроете. Если "все форматы" ограничиваются bmp/jpg/png, то тут за пару вечеров можно написать и самому (конечно, с либами типа libjpeg/libpng). А какая задача решается?

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно нечто типа PPM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)

Comment: imagemagick/graphicmagic/Qt/ffmpeg
Как сделать с помощью этого? Не очень понимаю.
Да и только png, потому что там есть прозрачность.
Про ppm не то что мне нужно.

Comment: связанный вопрос [python - RGB matrix of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25102461/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Извините, писать комментарии не могу но вроде [OpenCV](http://recog.ru/blog/opencv/206.html) такое умеет. Там свой тип для массива пикселей, но работать напрямую можно. Ну и все популярные изображения "хавает".

Comment: если упомяните `Mat img = imread( "image01.jpg");` то это в настоящий ответ может превратится. (правда я не вижу где прозрачность там, но легко добавить (`IMREAD_UNCHANGED`): [OpenCV : How to Load png images with 4 channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3803888/4279)).